# what is the security best practice for storing auth-key in session cookie?

Tags: php, web-services, api, security, slim

I have a restful web service API that does the following for authentication.

/login with username and password generates and returns an auth-key (API Key if you will) as JSON.

future requests should include the auth-key in the header for authentication or login again to get the auth-key

Now, I'm planning to create a website front end using java script and using the the restful web service api. The trouble is, generating login access keys for android or iphone applications keys work because, the first time, user will login and then the application will cache the auth key for future sessions. Now how do I do this with website front end? Should I store the auth-key in the cookie? If so, what prevents another user visiting my site sending the cached cookie? Is there a better alternative to this auth-key problem? Please point any security holes in this design.

Comment: You have two options. Either you make rotating the key easy, so when you think it is abused you can generate a new key (thats what popular client-side APIs do, like e.g. mapbox). Or you add the key on the server when it talks to the API, then the client will not see the key.

Comment: How do companies usually know api key abuse? Counting everytime an api is used just wastes instruction and if Im storing this count in a database, that's waste of space. However, I can write to disk.. The disk is cleaned on a regular basis though which will reset the count

Comment: A third option is using the existing Session Identifier for your user, and a middleware on the API endpoints that check to see if the request is coming from a browser. This does mean every request to the API goes through that check, but you can transform a session into an "auth-key" server side. From there, API usage is about as secure as your user's sessions.